# Nginx Removing First Sections Of URL

Tags: django, regex, nginx

I have   `Django/Django-CMS` website and I use Nginx to proxy pass `Gunicorn` and load static files. `Nginx` rules of `Django` and my template `js` plugins are getting confused by the including  style of functions of  theme. Basically theme loads only a `functions.js` file and all the rest of script files are  called from that file.

The problem is that, while  in the Homepage `'abctasarim.com/static/bootstrap.plugins.js'`, if I click about-us link, it is becoming `'abctasarim.com/en/about-us/static/bootstrap.functions.js'` and I get `404` error code. I tried to find a solution to make it in better way but now I am a little bit lost in the answers.

In my `nginx.conf`, my workaround is as below, which I am sure that can be  solved with regex without overwriting the rest of urls.

```
location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias   /home/ytsejam/public_html/luftchem/luftchem/static_cdn/;
    expires 365d;
    access_log off;
    #add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
}
location /en/about-us/static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias   /home/ytsejam/public_html/luftchem/luftchem/static_cdn/;
    expires 365d;
    access_log off;
    #add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
}
```

How can I write a `Regex` to loose to parts of url before the `static` part in sub urls?

Thanks